# Default outlet routes values in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have  a general `Artists` components which has this HTML :

```
<div tyle="float:left;width:40%;border:solid 1px gray;">
  <router-outlet name="left"></router-outlet>
</div>

<div style="float:right;width:40%;border:solid 1px orange;">
  <router-outlet name="right"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The *left* pane should contain Artists *list*
The *right* pane should contain Artist *details*

Here is the routes definition :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'artists',
    component:ArtistsComponent ,
      children: [
          {
              path: 'list',
              outlet: 'left',
              component: ArtistListComponent
          } ,
          {
              path: ':id',
              outlet: 'right',
              component: ArtistDetailsComponent
          }
      ]
}
 ,
  {
    path: '',
      pathMatch:'full' ,
    redirectTo: '/artists',
  }
]
```

So when The app is up , this is what I see

URL : `http://localhost:4200/artists`

[image]

And if I want to see both left pane and right pane I should navigate to :

URL : `http://localhost:4200/artists/(left:list//right:2)`

[image]

**Question :**

How can I declare a default outlet routes values ?

Something like :

```
...
{
   default:'list',
   path: 'list',
   outlet: 'left',
   component: ArtistListComponent
} ,
{
   default:'1',
   path: ':id',
   outlet: 'right',
   component: ArtistDetailsComponent
}
```

*NB*

I know I can redirect the app (at startup) straight to 
`http://localhost:4200/artists/(left:list//right:2)` , but I wonder if I can specify default values for outlets in the config itself

Comment: I would use the default option where the actual link or redirect is generated. Per say, in the navigation component, I would set up the defaults. So, unless you clicked or did a *specific action*, the parameter to send is the default one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use redirectTo with empty path:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'artists',
  component:ArtistsComponent ,
  children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'artists/(left:list)'
      },
      {
          path: 'list',
          outlet: 'left',
          component: ArtistListComponent
      } ,
      {
          path: ':id',
          outlet: 'right',
          component: ArtistDetailsComponent
      }
  ]
```

}